# Programmatically pass parameters to Apache Solr integrated with Search API

Tags: 8, search

I'm currently trying to enable spellcheck results with the search api. If I visit my apache solr server directly with http://myserver:8983/solr/d8/select?q=goood+worksd&spellcheck=true and provide the keywords and set spellcheck to true in the url parameters

I receive expected results

> {   "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]   },   "spellcheck":{
>       "suggestions":[
>         "goood",{
>           "numFound":1,
>           "startOffset":0,
>           "endOffset":5,
>           "suggestion":["good"]},
>         "worksd",{
>           "numFound":1,
>           "startOffset":6,
>           "endOffset":12,
>           "suggestion":["worked"]}]}}

In the response I can see the spellcheck information I need in the spellcheck section.

However when I set the options programmatically before doing the query with the search api I don't receive any of this information.

```
    $index_id = 'default_solr_index';
    $index = \Drupal\search_api\Entity\Index::load($index_id);
    $query = $index->query();
    $parse_mode = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.search_api.parse_mode')
        ->createInstance('terms');
    $parse_mode->setConjunction('AND');
    $query->setParseMode($parse_mode);
    $query->keys($search_terms);
    $query->setFulltextFields(['title', 'body_field_parse', 'type','field_description','name','body','field_title','field_summary']);
    $query->addCondition('status', 1);
    $query->sort('search_api_relevance', 'DESC');
    $query->setOption('spellcheck','true');
    $executed_query = $query->execute();
    var_dump($executed_query->getAllExtraData());
```

When I var_dump($executed_query->getAllExtraData()) all I get is

> { ["search_api_solr_response"]=> array(1) { ["response"]=> array(4) {
>   ["numFound"]=> int(0) ["start"]=> int(0) ["maxScore"]=> float(0)
>   ["docs"]=> array(0) { } } } }

I've done all kinds of variations giving true instead of 'true' and adding other options like

```
$query->setOption('spellcheck','true');
$query->setOption('spellcheck.build','true');
$query->setOption('search_api_spellcheck','true');
$query->setOption('spellcheck.extendedResults','true');
```

But nothing seems to work. I saw a spellcheck search api module someone posted but I couldn't get it to work and it seemed to do things very similar to how I'm doing it now. Is there a way to pass these parameters to my query to my apache solr? Or is my method correct and getAllExtraData not the proper way to get this information back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deep into the search_api_solr module I found a spot where it's applying options to the solr parameters inside the search method of the SearchApiSolrBackend class here

```
  foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
    if (strpos($option, 'solr_param_') === 0) {
      $solarium_query->addParam(substr($option, 11), $value);
    }
  }
```

I noticed that it only applies the parameter if it's preceded by 'solr_param_' and if it is it strips out the 'solr_param_' before applying it to the actual parameter.
All I had to do was add 'solr_param_' to the beginning of my option like so.

```
$query->setOption('solr_param_spellcheck','true');
```

Once I did that, getAllExtraData() returned what I needed.

> array(1) { ["search_api_solr_response"]=> array(2) { ["response"]=>
>   array(4) { ["numFound"]=> int(0) ["start"]=> int(0) ["maxScore"]=>
>   float(0) ["docs"]=> array(0) { } } ["spellcheck"]=> array(1) {
>   ["suggestions"]=> array(16) { [0]=> string(5) "goood" [1]=> array(4) {
>   ["numFound"]=> int(1) ["startOffset"]=> int(11) ["endOffset"]=>
>   int(16) ["suggestion"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "good" } } [2]=>
>   string(5) "goood" [3]=> array(4) { ["numFound"]=> int(1)
>   ["startOffset"]=> int(42) ["endOffset"]=> int(47) ["suggestion"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "good" } } [4]=> string(5) "goood" [5]=>
>   array(4) { ["numFound"]=> int(1) ["startOffset"]=> int(60)
>   ["endOffset"]=> int(65) ["suggestion"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4)
>   "good" } } [6]=> string(5) "goood" [7]=> array(4) { ["numFound"]=>
>   int(1) ["startOffset"]=> int(93) ["endOffset"]=> int(98)
>   ["suggestion"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "good" } } [8]=> string(5)
>   "goood" [9]=> array(4) { ["numFound"]=> int(1) ["startOffset"]=>
>   int(111) ["endOffset"]=> int(116) ["suggestion"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(4) "good" } } [10]=> string(5) "goood" [11]=> array(4) {
>   ["numFound"]=> int(1) ["startOffset"]=> int(129) ["endOffset"]=>
>   int(134) ["suggestion"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "good" } } [12]=>
>   string(5) "goood" [13]=> array(4) { ["numFound"]=> int(1)
>   ["startOffset"]=> int(154) ["endOffset"]=> int(159) ["suggestion"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "good" } } [14]=> string(5) "goood" [15]=>
>   array(4) { ["numFound"]=> int(1) ["startOffset"]=> int(182)
>   ["endOffset"]=> int(187) ["suggestion"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4)
>   "good" } } } } } }

Not entirely sure why I have so many duplicate results here so if anyone has input on that that would be helpful. Otherwise I do have the data I need.